# small sharepoint prob(about list view)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I created the list view and added edit function

when testing, I entered the new name 'test' and pressed OK, the file name didn't change, instead, it was like"test+oringnalfilename.aspx", why it append not replace?

here is the edit code:

```
<a href="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('__cancel;dvt_1_form_editkey={',$KeyValue,'}'))}">edit</a>
```

can anyone help me out?